# Invoke <h:commandLink> action method using <f:ajax>

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following code:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{testBean.showSomething}">
    Do Stuff
</h:commandLink>
```

which does what I want (change the state of testbean and reload the page which will show a different set of divs. because of their "rendered" properties)
Now I want to use ajax to accomplish this so I did this:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{testBean.showSomething}">
    <f:ajax event="click" render=":content" />
    Do Stuff
</h:commandLink>
```

However this causes the showSomething method to not even be called.
IMHO what I want to do is rather simple but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `event="action"` instead of `event="click"`. You could even omit it altogether. It's namely the default event the `<f:ajax>` is listening on when nested in an `UICommand` component.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{testBean.showSomething}">
    <f:ajax render=":content" />
    Do Stuff
</h:commandLink>
```