# Proper use of rendered= " " function

Tags: java, jsf

I'm creating an application as a school project using JSF, JavaDB and Java. To give you a short explanation a customer should be able to log in and select a menu or menus and then hit update. By hitting update the customer is redirected to a new page, on this page the customer are presented with a table containing the selected menus. The table is getting the information from an ArrayList< > that gets its objects added by a method collecting information from the database. The 3 last columns are meant to be filled out by the customer as these are unknown at that time. By hitting the Endre (change) button the 3 last columns should be changed to InputText fields where the customer can enter the information and then hit order which saves it and write the information to an Order table.

The problem:

When menu/menus are selected and the update button is entered the new page loads and presents the information as shown under.

[image]

So it seems to work just fine at this point, but when you hit the Endre (change) button the table disappear and no InputTextField is given.

It is using a boolean function isEditable to determine if the cells are to be shown as OutputField or InputField.

I have listed the code under:

In .html I have (its a repeating code so I post a section of it):

```
         <h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="enOrdre"
              styleClass="standard" headerClass="hode"rowClasses="oddeRad, likeRad" footerClass="fot">

<h:column>
    <f:facet name= " header " > #{mld.delivaddr}</f:facet>
    <h:inputText value "#{enOrdre.levAdr}" rendered = "#{enOrdre.editable" styleClass= "venstrejustert"></h:inputText>
<h:outputText value= "#{enOrdre.levAdr}" rendered = "#{not enOrdre.editable</h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

And with the Endre (Change) action:

```
<h:column>
<f:facet name= " header "> #{mld.edit}</f:facet>
<h:commandLink value= "#{mld.edit} " action= "#{order.editAction(enOrdre)}" rendered="#{not enOrdre.editable}"
</h:column>
```

My Class OrderBean with isEditable() and setEditable(boolean editable):

```
public class OrderBean implements java.io.Serializable {

private String brukernavn;
private int orgNummer;
private String firmNavn;
private String kontaktP;
private String epost;
private String menues;
private String levAdr;
private String levDato;
private int antP;

boolean editable;

public OrderBean(String brukernavn, int orgNummer, String firmNavn, String kontaktP, String epost, String menues, String levAdr, String levDato, int antP) {
    this.brukernavn = brukernavn;
    this.orgNummer = orgNummer;
    this.firmNavn = firmNavn;
    this.kontaktP = kontaktP;
    this.epost = epost;
    this.menues  = menues;
    this.levAdr = levAdr;
    this.levDato = levDato;
    this.antP = antP;
}

public OrderBean(){

}

public synchronized String getBrukernavn() {
    return brukernavn;
}

public synchronized void setBrukernavn(String nyBrukernavn) {
    brukernavn = nyBrukernavn;
}

public synchronized int getOrgNummer() {
    return orgNummer;
}

public synchronized void setOrgNummer(int nyOrgNummer) {
    orgNummer = nyOrgNummer;
}

public synchronized String getFirmNavn() {
    return firmNavn;
}

public synchronized void setFirmNavn(String nyFirmNavn) {
    firmNavn = nyFirmNavn;
}

public synchronized String getKontaktP() {
    return kontaktP;
}

public synchronized void setKontaktP(String nyKontaktP) {
    kontaktP = nyKontaktP;
}

public synchronized String getEpost() {
    return epost;
}

public synchronized void setEpost(String nyEpost) {
    epost = nyEpost;
}

public synchronized String getMenues(){
    return menues;
}

public synchronized void setMenues(String nyMenues){
    menues = nyMenues;
}

public synchronized String getLevAdr() {
    return levAdr;
}

public synchronized void setLevAdr(String nyLevAdr) {
    levAdr = nyLevAdr;
}

public synchronized String getLevDato() {
    return levDato;
}

public synchronized void setLevDato(String nyLevDato) {
    levDato = nyLevDato;
}

public synchronized int getAntP() {
    return antP;
}

public synchronized void setAntP(int nyAntP) {
    antP = nyAntP;
}

public boolean isEditable(){
    return editable;
}

public void setEditable(boolean editable){
    this.editable = editable;
}
}
```

Methods in my OrderRegistreringsBehandler:

```
    private ArrayList<OrderBean> tabelldata2 = new ArrayList<OrderBean>();

public String saveAction(){
    for(OrderBean orderBean : tabelldata2){
        orderBean.setEditable(false);
    }
    return null;
}

public String editAction(OrderBean order){
    order.setEditable(true);
    return null;
}
```

Hope someone can shed some light over this, in advance, thank you!

Comment: What's the scope of your `OrderBean` managed bean?

Comment: My Class OrderBean is within another Class OrderRegistreringsBehandler and the OrderRegistreringsBehandler has @ManagedBean(name="order") and @SessionScoped.

Comment: Then I don't understand how you are referencing it like `order`, when that refers to `OrderRegistreringsBehandler`. Shouldn't it be `order.orderBean` or something like that?

Comment: The OrderBean is a innerclass of OrderRegistreringsBehandler, but the methods and table are in OrderRegistreringsBehandler which has the method,
public synchronized List<OrderBean> getOrderList(){
        tabelldata2.clear();
        getInfoDB();
        return tabelldata2;
    }.

The value="#{order.orderList}" var="enOrdre" gets the information from that method listed over, in the Class OrderRegistreringsBehandler. Thats the reason i use order.orderList.

Comment: Ok. Then, first of all, you don't need to put the `synchronize` into your methods. That bean is `@SessionScoped`, so JSF will care about creating one for each of the end users. Secondly, I think you have this kind of problem because you're using an action method and submiting the whole form, which is creating a postback request. What you need is to ajaxify your command link, rendering your table again. Have a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393500/make-commandlink-use-ajax).

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have not had the time to do the changes and see if it works. But I'm going to work on the project today so I can give you a feedback later.

Comment: Hello, I have done the changes, but it did not work:/ I have looked at some other examples and see that they don't use List, but ordinary table to handle their objects, maybe its some kind of problem related to this?!? I will keep trying to make the necessary changes to get it to work, but if you or anyone else see something that might be wrong I would appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Ok, did your problem remain as it was before? Any difference? What do you mean about using table in order of list? I think you're doing it all right.

Comment: At the moment I really did not know what to do, I looked at some examples from my books and it consistently used a ordinary table [] to handle its objects, I thought that maybe for some reason the ArrayList and/or List<> had a problem with this kind of setup.

Comment: My problem basically remained the same with or without the f:ajax, but when I used ajax the information was presented, but when I pressed the change button  the system reported a nullpointer exception :/ I read a bit about f:ajax and found out that it should not be a problem with or without it, but I tried out a different approach.

Comment: I went back to @Named, removed the OrderBean I had as innerclass of OrderRegistreringsBehandler, created some new constructors, removed the unnecessary inputputText and outputText for the first cells, but kept it on the last 3 cells and tried again. The table remained the same even when I pressed the change button, but I was allowed to collect information from the db and past it as outputText and also write information in the last 3 cells, as if it had merged!?!? Even though I was able to make the changes and write the information to the database. So in a way it now works:P