# JSF2 - Pop up table using p:dialog reload and closes once a function is called

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

I'm new with JSF2.
Im trying to display a table using p:dialog.
This table has list of items and it has this delete function at the end of the row. My problem is when it clicked the delete, the whole page reloads and my pop up table closes.
However when it is not in the p:dialog, the delete function works properly.
My bean, whether it is view or session scoped, turns out the same output.

This is my delete code in my bean

```
public String delete(Items items) {

    getItemList.remove(items);
    return null;
}
```

snip in my xhtml,

```
<p:dialog header="Item Table" widgetVar="popUpTbl" modal="true" >
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable style="width:800px;height:485px;" id="popUpTbl" var="item" value="#{myBean.itemList}" >
                <p:column headerText="Item A">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.itemA}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Item B">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.itemB}" />                        
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Action">
                    <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{myBean.delete(item)}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>                
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Add id in `<h:form>` and `<p:dialog>` and update the form by giving fully qualified name which is nothing but in this case  `:dialogId:formId` and update it from `<h:commandLink>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h:commandLink makes` a full post and reloads the full page, you want to use ajax which `p:commandLink` does by default.

Try with

```
<p:commandLink value="Delete" process="@this" update="@form" action="#{myBean.delete(item)}" />
```

`process="@this"` because `p:commandLink` defaults to processing the whole form (which you don't need), and `update="@form"` because you need the whole form to be refreshed with the bean data (or at least the datatable, but that's equivalent to the form in your case).

You could have kept `h:commandLink` and done [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393500/invoke-hcommandlink-action-method-using-fajax), but its build into p:commandLink.

Comment: @Jaqen H'ghar if i am giving `update="form"` isn't it is going to update all the form which is present in the page ? or only dialog form it will update i think if we will give fully qualified name of form it would be better solution isn't it?

Comment: It will (should) only update the form the commandLink is inside

Answer (score 1):

Add id in `<h:form>` and `<p:dialog>` and update the form by giving fully qualified name which is nothing but in this case `:dialogId:formId` and update it from `<h:commandLink>` and one more thing i noticed your dialog widgetVar and the id of datatable is same which is wrong i have corrected in below example

```
 <p:dialog id="dialogId" header="Item Table" widgetVar="dialogIdWidget" modal="true" >
     <h:form id=formId>
        <p:dataTable style="width:800px;height:485px;" id="popUpTbl" 
            var="item" value="#{myBean.itemList}" >
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <p:column headerText="Action">
                        <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{myBean.delete(item)}" update=":dialogId:formId" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>                
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: i apply your suggestion but it still the same, the whole page loads resulting for the dialog to close whereas it should just load the dialog it self.

Comment: use `actionListener` in your `<h:commandLink>` and just for testing purpose use `commandButton` i think it should work and are you updating from `commandLink` becoz i forget to write `update` in `commandLink`, anyways i updated my answer take a look at it and try.

Comment: i got an error that the update attribute is not defined.