# jsf h:dataTable - not refreshing after deleting row

Tags: jsf

Hello Guys i need your help as usual

Jsf h:dataTable - not refreshing  after deleting row.

Not until i have to restart the programm.

what can i do please to resolve this problem?

Thanks John.

**ManagedBean**

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {

    if (customerList == null) {

        customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>(bookstoreManager.getAllCustomers());

        for (Customer cus : customerList) {
            System.out.println("Hello" + cus.getFirstName() + "......." + cus.getLastName());
        }
   }

    return customerList;
}
```

**Business Logik**

```
public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {

    TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createQuery("Select c from Customer c", Customer.class);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

XHTML Code

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:body>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />

        <h:form id="form">
            <h:dataTable var="cus" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1"
                width="400" styleClass="customerList"
                value="#{customerBean.getCustomerList()}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{texts.firstName}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{cus.firstName}" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ texts.lastName}" />
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="#{cus.lastName}" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{texts.address}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{cus.address}" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{texts.creditCard}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{cus.creditCard}" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{customerBean.selectCustomer(cus)}"
                        value="Edit" />
                </h:column>


                <h:column headerText="Delete">
                    <h:commandLink value="#{texts.delete}"
                        action="#{customerBean.deleteCustomer(cus)}" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: you haven't posted your .xhtml code, it would help to see how your dataTable is implemented

Comment: Sorry for that i have  posted it now.

Comment: try reading this other question and using the f:ajax tag inside your commandLink with the render attribute calling your dataTable ID. But remember you should update your customerList insied the deleteCustomer() method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393500/invoke-hcommandlink-action-method-using-fajax

Comment: Try reading your own question... Please reformat the code etc...

Comment: And you nowhere delete a row

Comment: Please  do you mean the form id?  If not, which is the datatable id then. And i try to update my customerList from  the deleteCustomer method in    the Business logik code by adding  "em.refresh"  still the list is not  refreshing.  New xhtml code with  "<f.ajax>"    <h:column headerText="Delete">
      <h:commandLink value="#{texts.delete}"
       action="#{customerBean.deleteCustomer(cus)}">
       <f:ajax render=":cus" />
       </h:commandLink>

Comment: em.refresh(customerList) in the  deleteCustomers method                                                                                        <h:column headerText="Delete">
       <h:commandLink value="#{texts.delete}"
       action="#{customerBean.deleteCustomer(cus)}">
       <f:ajax render=":cus" />
       </h:commandLink>